# java.util.NoSuchElementException - on iterating over sorted treemap

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I'm looping over my program, and for no certain reasons I've got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at EloRating.setNewSeason(EloRating.java:242)
```

This error points to the iterator loop.

```
TreeMap<String,Double> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,Double>();
                                    for (Entry<String, Double> team : teamsIntersection.entrySet()) {
                                        treeMap.put(team.getKey(), listTeams.get(team.getKey()).getRating());
                                        }

                                    SortedSet<Entry<String, Double>> listSorted = entriesSortedByValues(treeMap);
                                    Iterator<Entry<String, Double>> iter = listSorted.iterator();

                                    int stop = (amountOfIntersectTeams+1)/2;
                                    for(int i = 0; i < (stop-1); i++){
                        ----------->   iter.next();
                                    }
                                    double median = iter.next().getValue();
```

If I execute the program once, nothing special happens. But for some benchmark reasons I've to loop over the program 25.000 times with some slightly adjusted parameters.
And when I try to start the program again with the parameters from after an error, it will go further.  [At the moment of this error,  iterator contained 10 values]

### Goal

I want to have the upper median on the values of the Hashmap teamsIntersection.
e.g.  a-3 b-1  c-2  d-2   e-5 f-4 then I want the value of 3 back from a

### entriesSortedByValue

```
static <K,V extends Comparable<? super V>>
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map) {
        SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
                @Override public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> e1, Map.Entry<K,V> e2) {
                    return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                }
            }
        );
        sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
        return sortedEntries;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the same convention (i.e. `for (Entry<String, Double> team : teamsIntersection.entrySet()) {...}`) to iterate over your collection set?

Comment: Because I want the median of that set. - I shall put some extra info on it

Comment: Can we see the implementation for `entriesSortedByValues`?

Comment: I've added entriesSortedByValues

Comment: Similar question as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191687/how-to-calculate-mean-median-mode-and-range-from-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: Where is the value of `amountOfIntersectTeams` set? Why not just use `listSorted.size()`?

Comment: Sumitsu - it helped me well, by realising to changing my code so that i avoid the treemap by using a simple arrylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple entries with the same value, they will get *merged* by the comparator you've written, since `TreeSet` dedups elements relative to its comparator.

Assuming that `amountOfIntersectTeams` is the size of the map you're dealing with, that's my best bet as to what's going on.

To fix it, I'd consider adding a secondary comparison of the keys in your `Comparator` when the values compare as equal.