# iterating over sorted treemap: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator, treemap, sortedset

I have basic knowledge in Java and working currently on a Java based code.

EDIT: I didn't write the code

I am iterating over a sorted treemap of `Event` Objects and getting this exception when I am trying to get the next element:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)`

I think this should be due to the existence of mutiple entries with same value that are merged by the iterator comparator (be refering to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304796/java-util-nosuchelementexception-on-iterating-over-sorted-treemap), but I don't know how to find the keys used in the comparator. The object `Event` has many parameters (like id, time, etc)but not sure which one is used for the iterator.

Here is the related code portion (exception in the second `SimEvent first = fit.next();`):

```java
    if (future.size() > 0) {
        List<SimEvent> toRemove = new ArrayList<SimEvent>();
        Iterator<SimEvent> fit = future.iterator();
        queue_empty = false;
        SimEvent first = fit.next();
        processEvent(first);
        future.remove(first);

        fit = future.iterator();

        // Check if next events are at same time...
        boolean trymore = fit.hasNext();
        while (trymore) {
            SimEvent next = fit.next();
            if (next.eventTime() == first.eventTime()) {
                processEvent(next);
                toRemove.add(next);
                trymore = fit.hasNext();
            } else {
                trymore = false;
            }
        }

        future.removeAll(toRemove);

    } else {...}
```

EDIT: The hall code of `future` class:

```java
public class FutureQueue {

    /** The sorted set. */
    private final SortedSet<SimEvent> sortedSet = new TreeSet<SimEvent>();

    /** The serial. */
    private long serial = 0;

    /**
     * Add a new event to the queue. Adding a new event to the queue preserves the temporal order of
     * the events in the queue.
         * 
     * @param newEvent The event to be put in the queue.
     */
    public void addEvent(SimEvent newEvent) {
        newEvent.setSerial(serial++);
        sortedSet.add(newEvent);
    }

    /**
    * Add a new event to the head of the queue.
    * 
    * @param newEvent The event to be put in the queue.
    */
    public void addEventFirst(SimEvent newEvent) {
        newEvent.setSerial(0);
        sortedSet.add(newEvent);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator to the queue.
     * 
     * @return the iterator
     */
     public Iterator<SimEvent> iterator() {
        return sortedSet.iterator();
     }

    /**
     * Returns the size of this event queue.
     * 
     * @return the size
     */
    public int size() {
        return sortedSet.size();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the event from the queue.
     * 
     * @param event the event
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public boolean remove(SimEvent event) {
        return sortedSet.remove(event);
    }

    /**
     * Removes all the events from the queue.
     * 
     * @param events the events
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<SimEvent> events) {
        return sortedSet.removeAll(events);
    }


    public void clear() {
        sortedSet.clear();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed to debug this problem?

Comment: Would you please share the code of `future` class?

Comment: why you are using sometimes fit.next() without checking fit.hasNext()?

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov: done in the question edit

Comment: user7294900: I get this code this way. I have checked the iterator still have a next element just before I get the exception.

Comment: It's not clear whether you get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException (in the question) or java.util.NoSuchElementException (in the title).

Comment: @vempo: you're right, I made a mistake in copy-paste my exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDITED:* This is a common mistake. You cannot modify a collection directly (add or remove elements) when iterating through the collection using an `Iterator`. Removal, for example, must be done via the `Iterator` itself.

The correct way to do it is as follows (not a complete example, just to illustrate the point):

```
Iterator<SimEvent> fit = future.iterator();
while (fit.hasNext()) {
    SimEvent event = fit.next();
    processEvent(event);
    fit.remove();
}
```

Watch for other threads that might add to or remove from the collection while you are iterating through it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where a collection is used (only in `removeAll` method of `FutureQueue` class)?
The thing is that this code is working fine before I add other types of events to the queue.

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the actual code? Sorry for asking, but I'm looking at the source code of java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry and can't see any other reason for the exception. Did you try to run the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes it is. Actually I am working on a simulator developed by other people, I am adding other types of events to `future` elsewhere in the simulator using the `addEvent` method. I run the code in the debugger and I can see that `fit` has next element but getting the error.

Comment: I would also check if equals() and hashCode() of SimEvent are implemented correctly, and two equal SimEvent object always have the same hash code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: Can you post the code that initializes future? Do you add to/remove from future in a parallel thread somewhere? The point is that an iterator becomes invalid if someone modifies its enclosing collection after the iterator was created.

Comment: Yes, I am adding/modifying `future` in another class. For certain adds, it is working fine. `future` is declared this way in `Sim` class: 
`protected static FutureQueue future;`
`future = new FutureQueue();` In the basic version of the code, events are added to `future` using different methods of `Sim` class.

Comment: This might be a problem if you concurrently (in another thread) add an event between future.iterator() and fit.next(), because addEvent() modifies the collection. This could also explain why it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't - it depends on the timing of method calls.

Comment: This could be a reason, but the error is happening inside the `while(trymore)` loop, so It means at the time I assign `future` iterator in `fit`, even if `future` is modified that should not impact `fit`. Will the value of `fit` change even if I am not updating it inside the loop?

Comment: fit (Iterator) is impacted whenever the future (TreeSet) it was received from is modified. See above.

Comment: I managed to implement my events in a different way: I avoided adding them directly to `future` class. Thank you for the valuable comments!